# ParseInstaller.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground() is freezing my application

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am finding that about 1/5 of my tests are freezing, and after some searching for the problem I have narrowed it down to the line:

ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

I am using Parse 1.5.1, and an Android 4.4.2 device. My application class looks like:

```
public class InitApplication extends Application {

 @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Parse.initialize(this, "my_App_ID", "my_Client_Key");
        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);
        System.out.println("execution DOES reach here");
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
    System.out.println("execution DOES NOT reach here");
    }
}
```

The behaviour on my device is that I will first see a blank white screen for about 5 seconds, and then the screen goes black. I am not sure how long the screen stays black, as I usually force close. I've let it sit for about 10 minutes once with no change. I am unable to press the back button and any touch on the screen does nothing. I am forced to use my home button, then force the application to close. Upon reopening the application, it behaves and functions normally.

Further research led me to find this post: https://www.parse.com/questions/android-saveinbackground-lock-the-main-thread

But still, I have been unable to find a solution. One suggestion in the above post is to simply move the location of this code. I have tried this to some point after my main activity's onCreate() method (not to be confused with the application's onCreate() method). Behaviour appeared to be normal up until I got to the point where the getCurrentInstallation.saveInBackground() code is called, where my application froze and failed to respond until I forced it closed.

Are there any solutions to this problem?

Comment: Many of my app users reported the same problem (white screen or black screen). I suspected parse, but didnt actually confirm it. But reading this, I think it might be true. But problem was solved on reinstallation or force close (Not a good solution). Wierd.

Comment: Unfortunately, asking the user to force close isn't acceptable. This error occurs in several different cases. Fresh install from Eclipse, fresh install from .apk file, and updating from the current play store version. All three have led to the same issue. It does not happen every single time, but often enough to have a bad impact.

Comment: How about saving it in your own `Thread`?

Comment: I did not think that would be necessary since the `saveInBackground()` method does just that. I have implemented that into its own thread now and it worked initially, but I will have to test it more times to see if the issue still persists (since it does not occur every time).

Comment: I mean it's necessary to avoid `saveInBackground()` because freezes. My suggestion is to call `save()` in a `Thread` as a workaround.

Comment: Yes I switched to `save()` instead before my last comment. It appears to hang still, and if I go to my parse.com dashboard, I do not see the new installation appear. However, if I go back to `saveInBackground()` - while also inside my own thread - I will see the installation show up on my dashboard and see normal behaviour. Strange.

Comment: Having the same exact problem, sometimes even with an exception from the SDK (`com.parse.ParseException: at least one ID field (installationId,deviceToken) must be specified in this operation`). I really hope to find a solution, because I need to get push notifications to work..

Comment: Have you solved? How?

Comment: any updated , have you solve it ?

Comment: The current solution is to set you your own ASyncTask, then call the saveInBackground() function from there. It seems to work, but is definitely not the correct usage of the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the same problem as well using Parse SDK 1.5.1.

And I just downloaded the latest SDK 1.6.0 and problem solved.

[Link](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/android/existing) to download the latest SDK.

Comment: Hopefully the newest version solves the issue. I haven't had a chance to update yet. The proposed method of putting the saveInBackground() call into an AsyncTask did the trick for me up until now, but I will give it a shot.

Answer (score 2):

You can track reported issue here:
[Parse installation save causing app freeze](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/232990263561316/)

I already provided (confidentially) thread dump traces from my app. However at time of writing this post there is no useful feedback from Parse guys.

My humble opinion after looking into traces is a deadlock causing this issue after some trouble with server interaction. But it's just guessing.

**Link updated**

Comment: It looks like that bug report thread was closed due to inactivity.

Comment: Yes, however you can find evidence that same issue being reported by other developers end up closed as well. Maybe Parse doesn't recognise this bug as important or they simply deny it's existence. I'm sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

I do have the same issue and more.

The blank or black screen however happen not to all my test phones. It happens only to one of them (Android 2.3).

SaveEventually also does not work to the problematic phone above (all the other phones I have are working fine). It does not send data through successfully to the server. So I suspect that phone configuration of saving data on the phone itself before passing to the server when network is back on may be the issue.